# ¿Es posible validar los registros DNS según su fuente mediante PHP?

Tags: php, dns

Quiero hacer una validación de dominio por decirlo quiero hacer un array con los dominios autorizados que pueden hacer peticiones.
Es para un proyecto que tengo como estoy manejado subdominios dinámicos necesito validar su fuente si la fuente es valida o no. Por ejemplo:

Caso google:

Si tu apuntas un `CNAME = name="@" target="google.com"`

Resultado = pagina no exite no funciona.

Comment: En PHP existe una función que valida el DNS, no sé si es lo que necesitas pero podrías probar con este comando: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-check-record.php

Comment: dale checkeare la documentacion anduve revisado también las variables $_SEVER creo que me podria servir HTTP_HOST